# Vue2 - components lost during event handling completion

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

The website was originally bundled with vue-cli (vue2.7.14) and worked as expected.
Currently migrating to vite. After migration changes for vite, the app builds (BTW vite builds 18x faster yo-yay!). But an error occurs when handling a click event. With the good old vue-cli version, everything worked fine.

A modal button event
invokes an event handler in App (grandparent) component. The event handler is called and the handler code actioned, and appears to complete. However, at that point, the modal component, and it's parent component vanish from the vue component stack.

What I've tried:
Originally using an event bus, changed that to the more conventional event handler in the parent, re-emitting from there to the grandparent component. That works no differently, the handler is actioned, and again the parent and child components get lost somehow.

Stepping through code in the debugger, the child and parent component rendering vanishes here at  `copies[i]();` in flushCallbacks() - vue.js. It seems like the vue component hierarchy is being corrupted.

```
function flushCallbacks() {
  pending = false;
  var copies = callbacks.slice(0);
  callbacks.length = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < copies.length; i++) {
    copies[i]();
  }
}
```

Any suggestions for how to approach this, or what I might be doing wrong, would be most welcome.

BEFORE

[image: Before click event]

AFTER

[image: After event handling]